# TMemoryStream to array of bytes

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm attempting to get an array of bytes from a TMemoryStream. I'm struggling to understand how a memory stream works. To my understand I should just be able to loop through the MemoryStream using the `Position` and `Size` properties.

My expected result is to populate an array of bytes looping through the memory stream however when adjusting the `Position` property of the Memory stream it jumps from example 0 to 2 and then from 2 to 6.

```pascal
Data.Position := 0;
repeat
   SetLength(arrBytes, Length(arrBytes) + 1);

   Data.Read(arrBytes[High(arrBytes)], Data.Size);

   Data.Position := Data.Position + 1;
until (Data.Position >= Data.Size -1);
```

The above code results in partial or in some cases just no data at all. How can I correctly convert the data from a memory stream to an Array of Byte

Comment: Reading moves the position in the stream.

Comment: @Brian If I take out the `Data.Position := Data.Position + 1;` and debug it I can see that the Position does not change but stays at 0 making a endless loop. Is there something else I am perhaps doing wrong?

Comment: `Data.Read(arrBytes[High(arrBytes)], Data.Size);` attempts to fit 1561563 bytes (say) in a single byte. Probably you want `Data.Read(arrBytes[High(arrBytes)], 1);` and no `Data.Position := Data.Position + 1`. But this is an extremely slow and inefficient approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading data from `TMemoryStream` or any other stream for that matter the position is automatically advanced by the number of bytes read.

From [TMemoryStream.Read](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TCustomMemoryStream.Read) documentation

> Reads up to Count bytes from the memory stream into Buffer and
> advances the current position of the stream by the number of bytes
> read.

So if you are reading data from `TMemoryStream` sequentially you don't have to change the memory position yourself as it is done automatically.

Comment: This was the case but only when `TBytes` is used as the array. When using `TArray<Byte>` or `array of Byte` it seems the auto increment fails because no bytes are read. I always thought those 3 array types were the same but it appears not to be so. I need to do more research regarding bytes.